# How can i fix Debug App Check in win 8 certfication report

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, app-certification-kit

when i  test my app with the Windows App Certification Kit
i get the xml file with following error

---

Debug App Check
FAILED
    The App should not install any debug binaries.

```
    Error: Following errors were encountered while running the Debug Binary Check test.
        Failed to extract imported API information for this application.
    Impact if not fixed:       Windows Store policies do not allow submission of debug binaries. Please ensure that all submitted binaries are configured as release to avoid rejecting your submission.
```

### How to fix:       Binaries compiled as debug are known to fail this validation. Please always ensure your binary is compiled in release configuration and not debug configuration.

can some body help me to solve this issue

thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you need to certify a debug build? You should be running certification with a release build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Visual Studio project you're probably running the application by pressing F5 or clicking on the 'play' arrow in the toolbar? That installs and runs the app in debug mode.

Uninstall your application by right clicking on it on your Metro start screen, then choose uninstall. Then, back in Visual Studio, right click on your solution and select the Configuration Manager. The Active solution configuration is likely set to Debug, you want to change that to 'Release'